# How to fetch all the latest documents using elastic search based on timestamp

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, pycurl

I'm new to elastic search, i need to fetch documents which are newly affected or last 1 days using "get" and insert to a postgres table

The one i tried using search and giving now() - 1440m this is fetching entire records, i need only recent one's

Comment: what is inside the `GET _search {...}` call?

Comment: i gave _search?sort=create_date:now-1440m

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this request-payload while making your request to `/<index-name>/_search` :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
              "create_date": {
                  "gte": "now-1d"
              }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

No need to use any `sorting` how you have indicated in your comment. Just make request to plain `/_search` endpoint with this as payload.